# Why is the data in Angular Web API backend controller always empty after Angularjs POST request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, asp.net-core-webapi

Im new in angular, tried to search many posts but none helped me to receive data in controller method after angular js post. Does anyone know why parameters of model object are empty even though angularjs post sends the data?

this is the request payload which I found in chrome debugger, so I think all goes to bakend correctly..

```
{Name: "MyName"}
Name: "MyName"
```

FrontEnd:

```
   <div id="divMain" ng-app="testCtrl">
    <div id="divTblForm" class="border" ng-controller="ButtonsController">
       <input id="btnTest" class="inptSubmit right roundBorder" type="button" value="Test" ng-click="test()" />
    </div>
   </div>
```

here's the javascript (i tried to stringify, without stringify, property names in objToSearch quoted, not-quoted and so on..)

```
function getAngularApp() {
      return angular.module('testCtrl', []);
    }
app.controller('ButtonsController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.test = function () {

    var objToSearch = {
      Name: 'MyName'
    }

    $http.post("TestAngular/Test", JSON.stringify(objToSearch),
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    ).success(function (response) {
      alert(response)
    })
      .error(function (error) {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
});
```

Backend:
I tried with and without FromBody attribute and none of them brought success..

```
 [RoutePrefix("TestAngular")]
    public class TestAngularController : Controller
    {
        [System.Web.Http.Route("Test")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public List<Test> Test([System.Web.Http.FromBody]Test test)
        {
//breakpoint here, parameter 'test' values always empty or null..
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here's the model class

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Can anyone help please? I spent already more than 4 hours of searching similar topics and trying. it becomes really exhauasting. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the AngularJS code to post data using [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), which work as expected.

On AngularJS client

```
<script>
    function getAngularApp() {
        return angular.module('testCtrl', []);
    }

    var app = getAngularApp();

    app.controller('ButtonsController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.test = function () {

        var objToSearch = {
            Name: 'MyName'
        }

        $http.post("/TestAngular/Test", JSON.stringify(objToSearch),
            {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            }
        ).then(function successCallback(response) {
            //code logic here
            console.log("success");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("error");
        });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you can use postman etc tools to make request(s) with same testing data and check if your controller action can receive the data you sent. And if possible, you can create new project to implement same functionality then check if that new one can work well.